# I was wondering if there is a way to delete specific rows based on varying column and cell data in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that I regularly use to schedule preventive maintenance. The spreadsheet contains over 4300 rows and 600 columns. This is my master spreadsheet that I use to schedule maintenance.

The columns, starting at `"A"` contain

- Column `"A"` header `"system"`,
- Column `"B"` header `"sub-system"`,
- Column `"C"` header `"asset"`,
- Many columns in the range between column `"C"` header `"Asset"` and column `"EH"` `"Name"` that contain the weeks for three years and other headers
- Column `"EH"` `"Name"`,
- Column `"EI"` `"Date"`, and
- Column `"EJ"` `"Initials"`.

The cells associated with the weeks that are formatted for dates contain dynamic strings such as `"W-1, or IS-3, or E3-1"` in dynamic cells up and down the column. I have included a screenshot of an example of what I am looking for. The worksheet is named `Schedule` as well as the workbook. I would appreciate any assistance that you can provide using VBA to help automate this time consuming process.

[image: Schedule example]

Comment: please, consider a better title for your question; ref: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: also, it would easier to understand the issue with an example and/or attempts you may have tried.

Comment: I have researched how to loop through and check for specific cell information, and have not tried to create code in a module for this part yet. I am having trouble getting started and using the best approach to start with. I thought I would ask the experts, and start here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you simply want to delete all rows in the sheet, provided a certain criterion in Column D is met? The following code will do it, but please make sure to back up your file before trying it!

```
Sub deleteRowsBasedOnCriteria()
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test") ' change sheet name to correct one in production

    With sht
        lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
        For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1 ' presuming there are headers at the top in row 1

            ' if necessary, change the criterion or add more criteria --> this is just based on your example
            If .Cells(i, 4).Value <> "X" Then .Rows(i).Delete

        Next i
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

If you need to delete a really huge number of rows, it is recommended to set a range object instead and then delete them at once as it is more efficient, but I suspect the above code meets your requirements.

Comment: When running this code it yeilds a deletion of all empty rows with the exception of the header and those that contain "X". Two clarifications:

Comment: Hence why I wrote: "if necessary, change the criterion or add more criteria" as a comment over the conditional statement. This code should definitely get you started and could easily be augmented with several more conditions, for instance like this: `If .Cells(i, 2).Value = vbNullstring And .Cells(i, 4).Value <> "X" Then .Rows(i).Delete`

Comment: I greatly appreciate the code. It works great and I am adding more criteria.

Comment: Great. Please consider accepting the answer then. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

That's the intersection of rows with non-blank cells in column C, and rows with blank cells in column D:

```
Set r = Range("C:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Offset(, 1)
Intersect(r, r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: When running this code it yields a deletion of the assets and no string in the  column header for 1/2/2017. Is it possible to code and yield the desired result as indicated by the example?